# Need help with contradictory sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, slang

This is relatively simple sentence, but one part contradict another, so I don't understand what it should mean:

> 「なによこの気持ち悪い生き物は。海の生き物？**気持ち悪すぎて、一周回って可愛いわね**」

My attempt to translate it is:

> It's too gross and cute all around.

But this doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it means "It's so gross it goes all the way around to being cute again." It reminds me of the expression "It's so bad it's good."

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

According to the site below 一周回って is a kind of slang used by young people.

以前流行っていたことに回帰するという意味で
http://bosesound.blog133.fc2.com/blog-entry-856.html

It is often used in fashion or music to refer to something that was popular in the past, then becomes outmoded, but then becomes fashionable again.
It literally means "to go full circle".